# Windows server failover clustering dependencies

Tags: windows, failovercluster

I have 3 servers which with the following processes:

- Server 1: 1 process
- Server 2: 4 process
- Server 3: 1 process

What i need to configure after a failover is the following :

- On server 2 start the first 2 process
- On server 1 start the process
- On server 3 start the process
  Wait for a x amount of time then start the last 2 processes on Server 2

Can this be configured in WSFC ?

Answer (score 0):

Those details are a little to vague to answer definitively, but perhaps this information can help you get started.

If you look at the Microsoft doc for [Get-ClusterResourceType](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/get-clusterresourcetype), you can see that the following are types of resources that can be configured in a Windows Server 2019 failover cluster.

- DFS Replicated Folder
- DHCP Service
- Distributed File System
- Distributed Transaction Coordinator
- File Server
- File Share Witness
- Generic Application
- Generic Script
- Generic Service
- IP Address
- IPv6 Address
- IPv6 Tunnel Address
- Microsoft iSNS
- MSMQ
- MSMQTriggers
- Network Name
- NFS Share
- Physical Disk
- Print Spooler
- Virtual Machine
- Virtual Machine Configuration
- Volume Shadow Copy Service Task
- WINS Service

For as long as this link works, there is a great post from John Marlin (Microsoft Senior Program Manager for High Availability and Storage) which explains all of the possible cluster resources: [Windows Server 2016/2019 Cluster Resource / Resource Types](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/failover-clustering/windows-server-2016-2019-cluster-resource-resource-types/ba-p/372163).

What it will probably come down to for your question is whether or not the "process" is cluster aware, or if you process already fits into one of these pre-defined categories.

However, he also explains that "You can define your own resource types to provide customized support for cluster-unaware applications, enhanced support for cluster-aware applications, or specialized support for new kinds of devices. For more information, see [Creating Resource Types](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/aa369331(v=vs.90))."

Again, links are never a complete answer by themselves, but if you determine that you need to create a new resource type, then searching for "create failover clustering resource type" should get you there if/when the above links die.

Comment: Thanks for you answer i'm going to read the post hope they will help me